# position div outside table along 3 row

Tags: html

Consider the following table

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>some data</td>
        <td>some data</td>
        <td>&nbsp</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>some data</td>
        <td>some data</td>
        <td>need to display smthng here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>some data</td>
        <td>some data</td>
        <td>&nbsp</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to display something beside the second row. I've tried to have a third column and put `&nbsp` in cell(1,3) & cell(3,3) but it spoils the look as I need the table border also.

I think it would be better to position a div element outside the table but parallel to second row but I don't know how to do it. If I include a div element after second `<tr>..</tr>` ends, it doesn't help.

Can anyone suggest a solution ? I need the table borders.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like col-/rowspan, where you can fusionate rows and columns together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/4NxY7/

`position: absolute` will strip the element from the flow, so there is not even the need to rowspan it.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>some data</td>
        <td>some data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>some data</td>
        <td>some data</td>
        <td style="margin-left: 5px; position: absolute;">
            need to display smthng here
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>some data</td>
        <td>some data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can collapse cells vertically with [*rowspan* attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp)

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>some data</td>
        <td>some data</td>
        <td rowspan="3">need to display smthng here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>some data</td>
        <td>some data</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>some data</td>
        <td>some data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can check the output here : [jsfiddle.net/8DcAB/](http://jsfiddle.net/8DcAB/)

Comment: the border remains but will still give u a +1 .

Comment: What do you by borders remain? can you give a visual example of what you need as output?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you want to show parallel to that row, but check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mQZvx/ . Hope that Helps.

```
#myDiv{
position: relative;
float: right;
bottom:50px;
right:350px;
}
```

Comment: this will solve the problem but i was hoping for a better solution.

Comment: content will be a link,clicking on which will make an ajax call.

Comment: Ohk. Now check this updated fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/mQZvx/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/mQZvx/1/)